# Disable Checkbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

In my rails application I have this form in profile/_experience_fields.html.erb

```
    <div class="form-profile-half-last experselect end-date">
      <%= f.label :experience_end, class: "profile_label" %><br />
      <%= f.date_select :experience_end, {start_year: 1945, discard_day: true, order: [ :day, :month, :year ]}, :html=> {class: 'date-select'} %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-checkbox">
      <%= f.check_box :experience_current,:class => 'is_current', id: "checkbox_id" %>
      Je travail içi
    </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[class='is_current']").change(function() {
       if ($('#checkbox_id').is(":checked")) {
         $('.end-date select').attr('disabled', true);
         $('.end-date select').css("background-color", "#D9D8DD");
         $('.end-date select').css("color", "#D9D8DD");
         $('.end-date select').css("-moz-appearance", "none");  

       }
       else {
         $('.end-date select').attr('disabled', false);
         $('.end-date select').css("background-color", "white");
         $('.end-date select').css("color", "#333");   
       }
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

and this one in profile/edit.html.erb

```
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add another Experience" f, :experiences %>
```

Everything work fine except when I work with checkbox I have this problems

1- When Check the checkbox of the first experience the experience and date is disabled but all others experience and date are disabled two

2- Only the first form that is working others checkbox added with link to add doesn't work

3- If save a form with checked checkbox and try to edit it i find that the experience and date is enabled and not disabled even if the checkbox is checked

So I'm wondering on how can resolve all this problems and thank you for any help

Comment: Do  "$('#checkbox_id').prop("checked")" instead of "$('#checkbox_id').is(":checked")".  And do "$('.end-date select').prop('disabled', true);"  instead of "$('.end-date select').attr('disabled', true);" .

Comment: This hasn't changed anything

Answer (score 0):

Disabled elements form are not sent in the POST on a submit.